# neo4jclient execute delete function not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm using the example from https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples#delete-a-user-and-all-inbound-relationships

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .OptionalMatch("(user:User)<-[r]-()")
    .Where((User user) => user.Id == 123)
    .Delete("r, user")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

and change it to fit my needs to this

```
WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
    .OptionalMatch("(user:User)<-[r]-()")
    .Where((User user) => user.userId == userId)
    .Delete("r, user")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

but every time I can still get the user by

```
 User user1 = WebApiConfig.GraphClient.Cypher
        .Match("(u:User)")
        .Where((User u) => u.userId == userId)
        .Return(u => u.As<User>())
        .Results
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

what I'm doing wrong?

the Node labels is

> User

the properties labels are

> LastName, Name, FirstName, UpdatedTime, Email, facebookId, Picture,
>   userId

the define of graph db class

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "ActionApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


        //Use an IoC container and register as a Singleton
        var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GraphDBUrl"];
        var user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GraphDBUser"];
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GraphDBPassword"];
        var client = new GraphClient(new Uri(url), user, password);
        client.Connect();

        GraphClient = client;
    }

    public static IGraphClient GraphClient { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Try to match your user and your relation first, and see the result, maybe your match clause is the problem. Also, can you please provide a data structure example?

Comment: @supamiu did you main the node stracture?

Comment: I want to delete all relationship from and to this node

Comment: Could you please show us how "WebApiConfig.GraphClient" looks like?

Comment: my neo4j version is 2.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User)")
    .OptionalMatch("(user)-[r]-()")
    .Where((User user) => user.Id == 123)
    .Delete("r, user")
    .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

I imagine your user has outbound relationships, so won't be deleted as 'r' was only inbound.

Comment: now when i saw your example I understand my mistake :( , I did <-[r] instand of -[r] , thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old, but here is one current hint:

Use `DetachDelete` method instead of `Delete`. Then the relationships are automatically deleted without the need to search for them first.